# Cross compilation from windows 10 to raspberry pi CGO_ENABLED = 1

Tags: go, cross-compiling, cgo, go-sqlite3

I wish to compile for a raspberry pi from my windows machine (much faster).
Everything works if I use this command:
`env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 go build src/*.go`

However, I am using `go-sqlite3` which apparently requires CGO_ENABLED = 1

`Binary was compiled with 'CGO_ENABLED=0', go-sqlite3 requires cgo to work. This is a stub`

When I change the compilation command  to `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build src/*.go`
I get an error on windows

```
$ env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build src/*.go
# runtime/cgo
cgo: exec C:\Program: exec: "C:\\Program": file does not exist
```

This looks like a simple fix, but I'm not very comfortable with cross compilation. I cannot find much online.

**EDIT**:

I moved my project around, and now I get the following error:

```
$ env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build src/*
# runtime/cgo
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-marm'; did you mean '-mabm'?*
```

I looked around online, and apparently one needs to specify the CC:

```
$ env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc go build src/*
# runtime/cgo
cgo: exec arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: exec: "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

So, I'm moving forwards to fixing the issue, but I am not there yet.

I'll try finding how to install the gcc linux on windows and add it to `PATH`. However, if this is not the correct way of doing it. I'm open to some help

**EDIT2**

I donwloaded a tool chain from https://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/. I copied the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe` to `C:\Users\Me\go\bin`

Now I get another error

```
$ env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc go build src/*
# runtime/cgo
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

I'll keep posting my progress, but i'm sure the answer is dead simple. arf...

**EDIT 3**
Ok added the path to the system env and it is now found but...
I now get some linker stuff issues

```
$ env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc go build src/*.go
# command-line-arguments
C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc failed: exit status 1
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not found
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: I get `package src is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\src)` when I do that, I guess my configuration is bad

Comment: Try `go build ./src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so through the edits I showed the work.

To fix the initial problem `cgo: exec C:\Program: exec: "C:\\Program": file does not exist`
I moved the project in the GOPATH.

To fix the first edit `cgo: exec arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: exec: "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%`
I installed the toolchain from  https://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/ and made sure the  `C:\SysGCC\raspberry\bin` is added in both the user and system variables.

To fix the second edit `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not found` I installed https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download and made sure that the following packets were installed

- mingw-developer-toolkit
- mingw32-base
- mingw32-gcc-g++
- msys-base
  I'm not sure all of them are necessary.
  I also made sure that `C:\MinGW\bin` was in both user and system variables.

I then needed to restart all the terminals I worked with, and now the command compiles correctly

Comment: one year later and this issue rose again. I'm surprised this is the only place I found the answer I previously found. Is no one cross compiling go programs on windows for a raspberry pi?